# Certain polygons not obeying JavaScript style rules?

Tags: geojson, style, google-maps-api

[Styling misbehavior http://catalinagis.org/files/geojson_opacity.jpg](http://catalinagis.org/files/geojson_opacity.jpg)

http://catalinagis.org/ownership

You can see that some of the parcels don't follow the fill style rules (`opacity: 0.5`) even though the same style rule applies to all polygons in the data.  This happens when the data is loaded into http://geojson.io and http://mapbox.github.io/geojson-vt/debug/

Any ideas as to what is happening?

Comment: is this using openlayers?

Comment: @Mapperz No, Google Maps API

Answer (score 1):

It appears there is a bug in your JavaScript code where you switch the style, you put 0 for the opacity for polygons have ownership type as "Private", and you will need to change it to 0.5 to get it fixed:

```
case 'Private':
    return {
    fillColor: 'white',
    strokeWeight: 0.4,
    strokeColor: 'black',
    opacity: 0,
};
```

Comment: I see the bug you pointed out and changed the JavaScript and uploaded it to the server.  I don't see the change reflected, though, using IE, Chrome, or Firefox.  I have double-checked that the JavaScript has been changed, and it has.

Comment: also one of the SCICo parcels is solid blue, while the rest obey the `opacity: 0.4` rule in the switch